# Is "I wish I would have <done something>..." ever correct? (vs. "I wish I had <done it>...")

Tags: subjunctive-mood, would

I often hear (or read) a construct along the lines of "I wish I would have ". [Here is](https://daringfireball.net/linked/2021/10/28/facebook-meta) a recent example:

> I wish I would have written a post guessing at Facebook’s new name [...]

This *wish-I-would-have* form has never sounded correct to my ear; I would only ever say "I wish I *had* written..." in this case. I've always believed it to be a sort of subjunctive formation (?) error, but it's so common I'd like some definitive ruling on it or further context.

If it's not considered grammatical, why is it so common? Is it a valid dialect or regionalism?

There are [other](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357752/i-wish-would) [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291992/i-wish-you-would-have-died-vs-i-wish-you-had-died) on here that deal with adjacent or similar forms but I'm not sure they address this simple question squarely: I'm not asking about when "would-have" *could be* used, just whether it's correct here. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see anything ungrammatical.

Comment: I would never use it.

Comment: It's a common variant, complicated by the fact that _had_ and _would_ both contract to /d/ in speech (_if sheda done it, if sheddone it_), and epenthetic shwas are often added to contractions in speech, only to be interpreted as _have_'s. Oh, and it's not "subjunctive mood"; English doesn't have any. What it does have is modal auxiliaries and fast speech rules, which interact in unfortunate ways.